# How can i place binary values to particular position of multidimensional string array?

Tags: c#

I Declared multidimensional string array like this

```
 public String[][] DataArray = new String[][]
    {

      new String[]  { "2.1", "2.2", "3.6", "3.7", "3.8", "4.3", "4.4", "4.5" }, 
      new String[]  { "2.3", "2.4", "2.5", "5.1", "5.2", "4.6", "4.7", "4.8" }, 
      new String[]   { "2.6", "2.7", "2.8", "5.3", "5.4", "5.5", "1.1", "1.2" },
      new String[]   { "1.5", "6.1", "6.2", "5.6", "5.7", "5.8", "1.3", "1.4" },
      new String[]   { "1.8", "6.3", "6.4", "6.5", "8.1", "8.2", "1.6", "1.7" },
      new String[]   { "7.2", "6.6", "6.7", "6.8", "8.3", "8.4", "8.5", "7.1" },
      new String[]   { "7.4", "7.5", "3.1", "3.2", "8.6", "8.7", "8.8", "7.3" },
      new String[]   { "7.7", "7.8", "3.3", "3.4", "3.5", "4.1", "4.2", "7.6" }                                     

    };
```

I having set of binary values(For eg.01000010) in string array of size 8.this string array contains total 8 binary values set.For eg if i want to place 01000010 binary values to the position of 2 like in 2.1=0,2.2=1,2.3=0 ...etc.

For example i want to get output like this

```
public String[][] DataArray= new String[][]
    {

      new String[]  { "0", "1", "3.6", "3.7", "3.8", "4.3", "4.4", "4.5" }, 
      new String[]  { "0", "0", "0", "5.1", "5.2", "4.6", "4.7", "4.8" }, 
      new String[]   { "0", "0", "0", "5.3", "5.4", "5.5", "1.1", "1.2" },
      new String[]   { "1.5", "6.1", "6.2", "5.6", "5.7", "5.8", "1.3", "1.4" },
      new String[]   { "1.8", "6.3", "6.4", "6.5", "8.1", "8.2", "1.6", "1.7" },
      new String[]   { "7.2", "6.6", "6.7", "6.8", "8.3", "8.4", "8.5", "7.1" },
      new String[]   { "7.4", "7.5", "3.1", "3.2", "8.6", "8.7", "8.8", "7.3" },
      new String[]   { "7.7", "7.8", "3.3", "3.4", "3.5", "4.1", "4.2", "7.6" }                                     

    };
```

How can i do it?

Comment: There is no C language here. Removing that tag.

Comment: Excessive C# tags, removing them also.

Comment: Your question is very unclear, I'm looking forward to someone coming along who actually understands what you mean.

Comment: I want to place a binary value in particular position of multidimensional array.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "binary value" in Java and placing something into a position of an array is a trivial matter: `array[i][j] = myFavoriteValue`. Your question seems to point towards something completely different, though.

Comment: This seems like it may be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)- can you tell use what you want to achieve in the first instance as I am sure there is a more efficient way of doing it.

Comment: for example i want place "0" to the 2.1 position if array.?How can i do?

Comment: `DataArray[2][1] = "0"`---please explain what is wrong with that?

Answer (score 1):

The condition that the *n* <sup>th</sup> bit (starting at 0) of an integer `a` is set is:

```
a & (1 << n) != 0
```

Comment: Shouldn't you provide a boolean expression as a condition?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Hm, OK, done. Initially there was the "C" tag and this would have been evaluable in a boolean context. Cheers.

Comment: Do you get the question, though? I'm at a total loss.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Yeay, I'm pretty sure I know what the OP wants to do.

Comment: You must have psychic powers, then :)

Answer (score 0):

The following will populate DataArray with your bit values:

```
for(int i = 0; i < binaryList.Count; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < binaryList[i].Length; j++)
        DataArray[i][j] = binaryList[i][j];
```

**Edit:  Nevermind, misunderstood the question.**